# gRPC OOME and NPE in simple JMH benchmark

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, grpc

I tried gRPC, but gRPC use proto-buf immutable message object, I meet a lot OOM like

```
Exception in thread "grpc-default-executor-68" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Direct buffer memory
    at java.nio.Bits.reserveMemory(Bits.java:658)
    at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.<init>(DirectByteBuffer.java:123)
    at java.nio.ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(ByteBuffer.java:311)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena$DirectArena.newChunk(PoolArena.java:645)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocateNormal(PoolArena.java:228)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:204)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:132)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:262)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:157)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:93)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyWritableBufferAllocator.allocate(NettyWritableBufferAllocator.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writeKnownLength(MessageFramer.java:182)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writeUncompressed(MessageFramer.java:135)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writePayload(MessageFramer.java:125)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.writeMessage(AbstractStream.java:165)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerStream.writeMessage(AbstractServerStream.java:108)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerCallImpl.sendMessage(ServerImpl.java:496)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ResponseObserver.onNext(ServerCalls.java:241)
    at play.bench.BenchGRPC$CounterImpl$1.onNext(BenchGRPC.java:194)
    at play.bench.BenchGRPC$CounterImpl$1.onNext(BenchGRPC.java:191)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$2$1.onMessage(ServerCalls.java:191)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.messageRead(ServerImpl.java:546)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$1.run(ServerImpl.java:417)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: CANCELLED
    at io.grpc.Status.asRuntimeException(Status.java:430)
    at io.grpc.stub.ClientCalls$StreamObserverToCallListenerAdapter.onClose(ClientCalls.java:266)
    at io.grpc.internal.ClientCallImpl$ClientStreamListenerImpl$3.run(ClientCallImpl.java:320)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I'm not sure is this caused by object creation, I gave 5G mem to this process, still OOM, needs some help.

**EDIT**

I put my bench, proto, dependencies and an example out to this [gist](https://gist.github.com/wenerme/b428303d5f2d67c609af), the problem is the memory goes very high, sooner or later will cause OOME, and there is a strange NPE

```
严重: Exception while executing runnable io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$2@312546d9
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolChunk.initBufWithSubpage(PoolChunk.java:378)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolChunk.initBufWithSubpage(PoolChunk.java:369)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:194)
    at io.netty.buffer.PoolArena.allocate(PoolArena.java:132)
    at io.netty.buffer.PooledByteBufAllocator.newDirectBuffer(PooledByteBufAllocator.java:262)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.directBuffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:157)
    at io.netty.buffer.AbstractByteBufAllocator.buffer(AbstractByteBufAllocator.java:93)
    at io.grpc.netty.NettyWritableBufferAllocator.allocate(NettyWritableBufferAllocator.java:66)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writeKnownLength(MessageFramer.java:182)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writeUncompressed(MessageFramer.java:135)
    at io.grpc.internal.MessageFramer.writePayload(MessageFramer.java:125)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractStream.writeMessage(AbstractStream.java:165)
    at io.grpc.internal.AbstractServerStream.writeMessage(AbstractServerStream.java:108)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerCallImpl.sendMessage(ServerImpl.java:496)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$ResponseObserver.onNext(ServerCalls.java:241)
    at play.bench.BenchGRPCOOME$CounterImpl.inc(BenchGRPCOOME.java:150)
    at play.bench.CounterServerGrpc$1.invoke(CounterServerGrpc.java:171)
    at play.bench.CounterServerGrpc$1.invoke(CounterServerGrpc.java:166)
    at io.grpc.stub.ServerCalls$1$1.onHalfClose(ServerCalls.java:154)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$ServerCallImpl$ServerStreamListenerImpl.halfClosed(ServerImpl.java:562)
    at io.grpc.internal.ServerImpl$JumpToApplicationThreadServerStreamListener$2.run(ServerImpl.java:432)
    at io.grpc.internal.SerializingExecutor$TaskRunner.run(SerializingExecutor.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Comment: Can you tell us some more about your program rather than just showing us an OOM error?

Comment: @LouisWasserman Sorry about that, I update my question to include the code, proto and output, BTW, this is a JMH benchmark test.

Comment: GitHub issue: https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1216

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that StreamObserver.onNext does not block, so there is no push-back when you write too much. There is an [open issue](https://github.com/grpc/grpc-java/issues/1216). There needs to be a way for you to interact with flow control and be informed that you should slow your sending rate. For client-side, a workaround is to use ClientCall directly; you call Channel.newCall all then pay attention to isReady and onReady. For server-side there isn't an easy workaround.